# when i try to add more than 1 textbuttons to a single column It shows The named parameter 'child' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() => runApp(const CustomXylophoneApp());

class CustomXylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomXylophoneApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: Scaffold(
        body:

        SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('assets_note1.wav');

                  TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.red);
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('assets_note2.wav');

                  TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.blue);
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('assets_note3.wav');

                  TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.blueGrey);
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('assets_note4.wav');

                  TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.green);
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('assets_note5.wav');

                  TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.teal);
                },
              ),
               TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('assets_note6.wav');

                  TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.blueAccent);
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('assets_note7.wav');

                  TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.pink);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `child` for each `TextButton` like I am using Text widget on it

```dart
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    AudioCache player = AudioCache();
    player.play('assets_note1.wav');

    TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.red);
  },
  child: Text("Button Name"), //this
),
```

More about [`TextButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

add **child** property in TextButton like this

```
  TextButton(
            child: Text("Play"),
            onPressed: () {
              AudioCache player = AudioCache();
              player.play('assets_note2.wav');
              TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.blue);
            },
  ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).